# Error with the New repository , How to solve it?

Tags: git

It's a problem with

> ...or push an existing repository from the command line
>
> ```
> git remote add origin git@github.com:janbogosyan/goku-two.git
> git branch -M main
> git push -u origin main
> ```

When I am trying to push an existing repository from the command line in the terminal, it gives me this `Error: remote origin already exists`. So I change the origin via new name through git remote, but when I check `git remote -v` I can see I have a lot of different names and this looks somehow wrong every time to set different name. Is there any solution or is it just not a problem at all?

Comment: We can't guess why your repositories already have `origin` remotes but you're still trying to push them to new remote repos. It's unclear what position you're starting from or where exactly you're trying to get to.